# What Objective-C NSString method need to check if a string is contained in another?

Tags: nsstring

What method of NSString checks if a string found by a `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: keyword` is contained in another?

```
NSString *listOfNames = @"anas, ward, qusai, zainab";
NSString *keyword = @"Ward";

if ([listOfNames localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:keyword]) {
    NSLog(@"\nMatch found!\n");
} else {
    NSLog(@"\nNo match found!\n");
}
```

Comment: I cannot relate your question to the code. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Eiko how to return actual string found from `listOfNames`? here `"Ward"`..with capital W.

Comment: Use one of the rangeOfString: methods with the right options as @Josh Caswell says. Given the range, you can then easily get the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean you're using `localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:` since the method you've cited doesn't do what you're saying.

There's a corresponding method to get the range of the search term: [`-[NSString localizedStandardRangeOfString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1413574-localizedstandardrangeofstring?language=objc) You use the returned range to index back into the source string.

You can also use the `rangeOfString:options:range:locale:` if you need to search with a locale other than the current one.

Answer (score 1):

The `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` most likely internally converts both strings to lowercase and then does a compare using a localized collation algorithm.

From the docs:
"Localized string comparisons are based on the Unicode Collation Algorithm, as tailored for different languages by CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository). Both are projects of the Unicode Consortium. Unicode is a registered trademark of Unicode, Inc."

Probably a reasonable thing to do is convert each string to lowercase, using something like `listOfNames.lowercaseString`

Comment: thanks, but what i meant...the output here is `// Match found!` when i search for ward (lowercase)...but what i need more, is to get `// Match found! Ward ..!`...Ward here is the actual value in the string.

Comment: Perhaps do a regex match?